# Is 'keep in secret' correct?

Tags: meaning, differences

Are both correct?

Information was kept in secret.

Information was kept a secret.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.  Both mean very different things.

You can keep kittens in secret.  You can keep information in secret.  Doesn't mean the information is a secret.  It just means you're keeping the fact that you're keeping information is a secret.  You could be keeping widely published  dictionary.  Not sure why you don't want people knowing you have a dictionary.

Now if you keep secret information in secret you're really being sneaky.

Comment: A bit controversial. If I keep kittens in secret they become a secret.

Comment: I don't think so. The keeping of kittens is not the same thing as kittens. Things that are different things can be different things. A kitten could go into politics, get elected president, and lead a very public life. Yet keep the fact that it is a kept kitten a secret because that would ruin a promising political career.

Answer (score -1):

Both examples about "Information" sound odd.

"Information was kept in secret."  This means the act of keeping the information was secret (and unexpected).  e.g. "My telephone provider recorded every call I made, without telling me.  They kept information in secret."    It would sound more natural to say "They secretly kept information."

"Information was kept a secret."  I think you would say "Information was kept secret."  e.g. "It wasn't an open trusting environment at my last job.  Information was kept secret."

A particular piece of information can be a secret.  "Actually I was already married, but I kept that a secret!"